# Magento 2 - Add additional DIV in sub menu

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento 2.1.6. I want to add an extra wrapper `<div>` around the submenu items in Top menu.
When we Hover over a menu item, the submenu shows up, submenu is a `<ul>`, I want to wrap this `<ul>` inside an external `<div>` i.e. "submenu-wrapper" so there will be multiple `<ul>` in the submenu-wrapper.
Please guide me how can I get this structure. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it in Topmenu.php

Comment: Can u share your solution please if u found it.